# How to get the most frequent element without group by in XQuery 1.0?

Tags: xml, xquery

I'd like to extract the most frequent element from a list.

The list `$listOut` is composed by element of this type:

```
<Outcome>
  <Parameter>B</Parameter>
  <Value>15</Value>
  <MinVal>1</MinVal>
  <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
</Outcome>
<Outcome>
  <Parameter>A</Parameter>
  <Value>15</Value>
  <MinVal>1</MinVal>
  <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
</Outcome>
<Outcome>
  <Parameter>D</Parameter>
  <Value>43</Value>
  <MinVal>34</MinVal>
  <MaxVal>36</MaxVal>
</Outcome>
<Outcome>
  <Parameter>B</Parameter>
  <Value>4</Value>
  <MinVal>1</MinVal>
  <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
</Outcome>
```

What I'd like to obtain is `<Parameter>B</Parameter>`, because parameter B is present 2 times so it's the most common.

I've no idea of how to do this I cannot use the `group by` statement. (only For, Let, Order By, Where, Return)

I've thought to do something like this:

```
for $outOk in distinct-values( $listOut )
let $paramOk := //Outcome[Parameter eq $outOk]
order by count( //Outcome[Parameter eq $outOk] )
return $paramOk
```

But it naturally doesn't work.

Comment: As is, your question is incomplete and cannot be answered as it's missing very important information. The most frequent element from a list containing a single element is this single element. Please edit your question to contain: reasonable example input (multiple elements, so there are also non-maximal elements), expected output and an explanation what's wrong with your current code. [How to post an SSCCE](http://sscce.org) provides a great tutorial on how to post good questions.

Comment: Please post a larger sample document with multiple elements, what you expect the outcome to be, and what the outcome actually is.  Tell us why the actual output is not what you expected.

Comment: @JensErat I think that no more XML is needed, simply **$listOut** is a list of elements **Outcome** . I added some more code to be clearer

Comment: @Matthew I added something, I hope that now it's clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Distinct values can only be determined on atomar values, not whole subtrees. Instead, query for the distinct values of the parameters, then count the elements matching this parameter, order by the parameter occurrences and finally limit to a single result.

```
let $listOut := (
  <Outcome>
    <Parameter>B</Parameter>
    <Value>15</Value>
    <MinVal>1</MinVal>
    <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
  </Outcome>,
  <Outcome>
    <Parameter>A</Parameter>
    <Value>15</Value>
    <MinVal>1</MinVal>
    <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
  </Outcome>,
  <Outcome>
    <Parameter>D</Parameter>
    <Value>43</Value>
    <MinVal>34</MinVal>
    <MaxVal>36</MaxVal>
  </Outcome>,
  <Outcome>
    <Parameter>B</Parameter>
    <Value>4</Value>
    <MinVal>1</MinVal>
    <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
  </Outcome>
)
return
  (
    (: loop over the set of distinct parameter values :)
    for $parameter in distinct-values( $listOut/Parameter )
    (: for each of them, count its occurences :)
    let $occurences := count($listOut[Parameter eq $parameter])
    (: order the result set by the occurence count in descending order :)
    order by $occurences descending
    return $parameter
  (: limit to the first result, which is the parameter value occuring most :)
  )[1]
```

Comment: I'd like to understand better what your solution does, tell me if what I think can be exact:   **for**: browses all the Parameters   **let**: creates a list of 1 element with the occurences of that parameter in the list  **order by**: orders how the initial parameter will be printed in descending mode  **return** and [1]: print only the first element of for  Is it correct or is there a better explanation?

Comment: Your explanation seems fine. I added some comments to the code explaining every line. Some notes: the `for` line browses the _distinct values_  of parameters. The `let` line indeed create single element lists, but this is a very nifty XQuery implementation detail and not relevant here -- you could simply consider it a single numeric value for this query. Your other explanations are fine in my opinion.